# Is there a better way to delete files as soon as they become 5 minutes old other than using Bash, find via a cron job?

Tags: linux, find, cron

I am using a Bash script via a cron job to delete files as soon as they become 5 minutes old. I there a better approach than this?

Is there—maybe—a way to monitor my filesystem more efficiently and get a callback once a certain condition (e.g. "File is older than 5 minutes") is met?

**Background**: Our scanner is not very "smart" and only supports to upload scans to an FTP server. While it is not secure, there is currently no better way to do it. In order to prevent the FTP server becoming a treasure trove of potentially valueable documents, I would like to delete them as soon as they are 5 minutes old.

The first idea was to run a cron job every 5 minutes that just deletes all the files in that directory. The obvious downside is that, if someone scans a document right before the cronjob runs, they lose their scan. It might not be an issue, since you could just re-scan the document, but it's annoying.

The next approach was to run a cron job every 5 minutes, that checks if a file is older than 5 minutes, and if so, deletes it. This would give a file a theoretical maximum lifespan of ~10 minutes. It works, but it feels a bit like a hack.

So is there a better way?

Comment: I find nothing hacky in a cron job with proper `find`. I can think of a solution using inotify (each new file triggers its own instance of a script, the script waits 5 minutes and removes the file) but recurring `find` is more robust (example where the script fails: reboot before the file is removed). Two improvements: (1) A `README` file with a warning that other files in the directory will be removed. The cron job shouldn't delete this file, it should keep recreating it in case somebody else deletes or overwrites it sometimes. (2) The job should exit if the previous one is still running.

Comment: Why do you think using a cron job is a “bad” solution? The vast majority of systems in the world use cron jobs similar to this. Using find via Bash and via a cron job is 100% fine. I have tons of cron jobs running on various servers every minute; it’s no big deal.

Comment: "Better" is subjective. Are you asking if there is some built in OS capability to do this?

Comment: "*..run a cron job every 5 minutes, that checks if a file is older than 5 minutes, and if so, deletes it. This would give a file a theoretical maximum lifespan of ~10 minutes.*".  What about run it every 5 seconds instead?

Comment: @lx07 You can’t run Cron jobs at increments of less than a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is nothing that is really that better than a basic cron job that calls a Bash script in many cases.

Why do you think using a cron job is a “bad” solution? Unless this method is causing an actual issue on your system, changing it to something else would only overcomplicate what is—essentially—a simply process.

The vast majority of systems in the world use cron jobs similar to this. Using find via Bash and via a cron job is 100% fine.

That said, this is how I would handle the task you describe via a crob job…

First, you could use [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) like this:

```
find /path/to/the/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +5 -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(PDF|JPG|TIFF)$' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Then you can test the command like this; swapping out `rm -f` with `ls -la`:

```
find /path/to/the/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +5 -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(PDF|JPG|TIFF)$' -exec ls -la {} \;
```

This is specifically looking for files (`-type f`) older than 5 minutes (`-mmin +5`) with the PDF, JPG and TIFF file extensions (`-regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(PDF|JPG|TIFF)$`) in the path `/path/to/the/files`, only look in that directory (`-maxdepth 1`).

You can add other file extensions as needed or just remove it altogether to just scan the directory for anything. But I don’t recommend that since you run the risk of deleting things that shouldn’t be deleted; just add needed extensions as needed.

Feel free to test and adjust as needed. I would recommend placing this code in a Bash script file and then run that Bash script file via the cron job. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
find /path/to/the/files -maxdepth 1 -type f -mmin +5 -type f -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(PDF|JPG|TIFF)$' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of what I had already stated that I am doing. My question specifically on how to do it **better** than this, because the cron job runs so often, specifically the "watch filesystem and get callback on event" part.

Comment: Unless this method is causing an actual issue on your system, changing it to something else would only overcomplicate what is—essentially—a simply process.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`inotifiywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to be told that a file is created in some directory, and then start a background process that sleeps 5 minutes and then erases the file.

However, this solution wouldn't be very robust, since if for any reason you miss a file it will stay forever on the disk. The solutions based on `find` will eventually cleanup lingering files, even if for some reason a run failed.

Comment: In short the question is "is there a *better* way than `find` via cron?". You introduce another way and then you explain why it is *worse*. Oh well…

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski There is  a difference between `find` being the only solution and `find` being the best solution...

Comment: @xenoid Using `find` is the most practical and stable solution because any other solution would be esoteric at best with marginal benefit at most. And if this person leaves this job, debugging a Bash script running a process like this is easier than most any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `logrotate`. I believe you can specify arbitrary directory paths allowing it to be used for things other than log files.

Comment: But log rotate still works on a schedule—and dare I say it—via a cron job even if you are not aware of it.